# Stop a CPU-intensive operation by pressing a GTK button

Tags: c, gtk, glib

I'm extending a GTK-application that does a group of operations that takes high CPU loads. I want to include the possibility to stop this operation by clicking on a button in the GUI.
The problem is that, as expected, the signal coming from the button is actually fired just after the operation is completed.

For now, the code kinda looks like this:

```
[...]
// code snippet to show the dialog and to enable user interactions with the buttons on the lower side of the window
while(TRUE) {
    gint run = gtk_dialog_run (window_main);
    if (run == GTK_RESPONSE_APPLY) {
        gboolean success = start_long_operation();
    }
    else if (run == GTK_RESPONSE_HELP) {
        open_about();
    }
    else if (run == GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL) {
        stop_long_operation();
    }
    else {
        gtk_widget_destroy (window_main);
        return;
    }
}
```

I've declared a global variable `busy_state` that is checked by the long operation's function: if it is TRUE, simply the inner loop continues to cycle. Else, the loop exits and the function returns a result.

`stop_long_operation()` simply sets this global var to FALSE.

As written before, I can't press the "stop" button and "send" GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL until the operation finishes, because it blocks the entire window.

I've tried the use of `while (g_main_context_iteration(NULL, FALSE))` trick inside the `stop_long_operation()` function, as explained in the gtk's docs, but without results.

Do I really need to set up a multithread functionality? Can I avoid this?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, you will need multithread, because you need to interfere in a subprocess that runs concurrently with your main aplication. Doing this, you just need to set a flag (to false) that is used by the multithreaded operation to verify if it needs to continue running.

Comment: Ok thanks, does the g_thread_create() function fits my needs? In other words, whats the best method to start the long operation concurrently with the main application?

Comment: Alessandro, unfortunatelly I never worked with threads in C, so I'm not sure to answer this :(

Comment: @davidbuzatto: I think that GTK might have their own option, but on UNIX it's `pthread`s, and on Windows, it's some Win32 call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can break up your long operation into multiple smaller tasks you may be able to avoid using threads.  The easiest way would be to just create a callback that you would pass to [g_idle_add](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add) (or [g_idle_add_full](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add-full)).  Each time the callback runs it does a small amount of work, then returns TRUE.  When the the task is completed, return FALSE and the callback not be run again.  When you would like to interrupt the task, simply remove the callback by passing the value returned by g_idle_add to [g_source_remove](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-remove).

If you can't break up the operation then threads are pretty much your only choice.  [g_thread_new](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html#g-thread-new) is the low-level way to do that, but it's generally easier to use a [GThreadPool](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Thread-Pools.html).  A more advanced option would be to use [g_simple_async_result_run_in_thread](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSimpleAsyncResult.html#g-simple-async-result-run-in-thread).

Comment: I started working on multithread support with g_thread_new() few days ago, but I've been stopped by another GTK developer that advised me, in fact, that the best way is to use g_idle_add(), without an explicit creation of new threads.
And it worked ;) Thank you everyone

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option if you don't want to use threads (although you should use threads and this is very insecure):

Use processes. Processes are much simpler, and can allow you some greater flexibility. Here's what you need to do:

- Create another C/C++/Any language you want program that does the task
- Spawn it using `spawn()` or `popen()`
- (Optional) Pass arguments using the command line, or IPC
- When the button is pressed, use either the `kill()` call on UNIX, or the Win32 kill function to kill the process. You can use `SIGTERM` on UNIX and register a handler so that you can have a controlled shutdown.